# Libgdx background image not fitting

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am developing a game which has 480x800 VIRTUAL screen sizes. Also I render my map using `TiledMapRenderer`. My problem is fitting background and HUD elements into the screen which has different ratio than 480/800 (Mostly taller devices). Some devices show blank area at the bottom of screen.

```
//my viewport (WIDTH = 480, HEIGHT = 800)
viewport = new ScalingViewport(Scaling.fillX,MyGdxGame.WIDTH,MyGdxGame.HEIGHT,camera);

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height, true);
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
    barriers.getRenderer().setProjectionMatrix(viewport.getCamera().combined);
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(viewport.getCamera().combined);
}
```

My screen should fit the X, but background image should fit X and Y without changing the aspect ratio. In this case ScalingViewport does not solve my problem, and if I change the viewport, I have to code everything from beginning.

```
 @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);
        SpriteBatch sb = game.batch;
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(46f/255,46f/255,46f/255,1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        sb.begin();
    //this has to change in somehow
    sb.draw(AssetManager.backgroundMenu,0,0,MyGdxGame.WIDTH,MyGdxGame.HEIGHT);
        sb.end();
     }
```

Should I use multiple viewport? Or is there any way to fit my background into the screen? By the way I do not want to change my camera if there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use second viewport for your HUD elements.

I would recommend using [ExtendViewport](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/ExtendViewport.html)

```
ExtendViewport viewport = new ExtendViewport(MyGdxGame.WIDTH,MyGdxGame.HEIGHT);
```

It fills all screen (without black bars) and keeps aspect ratio for all resolutions.